# How to update values of a column of a table with values from other in SQL (timestamp based)?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I need to update empty values in a table with values presents in another table. Shortly these values are ids of groups, and I need to pass these groupids in all events of my users to recognize in which group the user held this event.
Example:

**Inputs:**

**Table A:**

| event | timestamp | groupid | userid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| created | 2021-03-09T09:58:17.198362522Z |  | c98 |
| updated | 2021-03-09T09:59:17.198362522Z |  | c98 |
| created | 2021-03-09T09:46:17.198362522Z |  | a32 |
| updated | 2021-03-09T10:20:17.198362522Z |  | c98 |
| updated | 2021-03-09T10:22:17.198362522Z |  | c98 |
| created | 2021-03-09T09:58:17.198362522Z |  | a32 |
| created | 2021-03-09T10:40:17.198362522Z |  | c98 |

**Table B:**

| groupid | timestamp | userid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f13 | 2021-03-09T09:58:17.198362522Z | c98 |
| f14 | 2021-03-09T10:15:17.198362522Z | c98 |
| ad8 | 2021-03-09T09:45:00.198362522Z | a32 |
| ad9 | 2021-03-09T09:58:17.198362522Z | a32 |

**Desired Output:**

**Table A:**

| event | timestamp | groupid | userid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| created | 2021-03-09T09:58:17.198362522Z | f13 | c98 |
| updated | 2021-03-09T09:59:17.198362522Z | f13 | c98 |
| created | 2021-03-09T09:46:17.198362522Z | ad8 | a32 |
| updated | 2021-03-09T10:20:17.198362522Z | f14 | c98 |
| updated | 2021-03-09T10:22:17.198362522Z | f14 | c98 |
| created | 2021-03-09T09:59:17.198362522Z | ad9 | a32 |
| created | 2021-03-09T10:40:17.198362522Z | f14 | c98 |

Comment: Why not use a simple JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

isn't it just a simple join ?

```
update table1 a
set groupid = (select groupid from table2 b
                where a.userid = b.userid
                and a.timestamp >= b.timestamp
                order by b.timestamp desc
                limit 1
              )
where a.groupid id null
```

Comment: You usually don't update tables in Athena as the data is based on files in S3, however, you can create a VIEW with the JOIN command

Comment: The timestamps usually are not the same

Comment: then , maybe choose the last one before or at the eventtime? see updated answer. or you can change the <= to choose  the first one  after or at the eventtime if it makes more sense